# подскажите, пожалуйста, на что ругается Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

```
ValueError at /newpost
The view app.views.newpost didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/newpost
Django Version: 1.11.26
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view app.views.newpost didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 198
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe
Python Version: 3.6.7
Python Path:    
['D:\\01django\\DjangoWebProject6',
 'D:\\01django\\DjangoWebProject6',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_display',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36',
 'C:\\Program Files\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files\\JetBrains\\PyCharm '
 '2019.3\\plugins\\python\\helpers\\pycharm_matplotlib_backend']
Server time:    Сб, 21 Дек 2019 04:37:33 +0000
```

**views.py**:

```
def newpost(request):
    """Renders the newpost page."""

    if request.method == "POST":
        blogform = BlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if blogform.is_valid():
            blog_f = blogform.save(commit=False)
            blog_f.posted = datetime.now()

            blog_f.save()

            return redirect('Блог')

        else:
            blogform = BlogForm()

        assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest)
        return render(request, 'app/newpost.html',
            {
                'blogform: blogform,'

                'year': datetime.now().year,
            }
        )
```

**forms.py**:

```
class BlogForm (forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog # используемая модель
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'content', 'posted', 'author', 'image') # требуется заполнить указанные поля
        labels = {'title': "Заголовок", 'description': "Краткое описание", 'content': "Содержание", 'posted': "Дата", 'author': "Автор", 'image': "Путь к изображению"} # метка к полю формы text
        labels = {'title': "Заголовок", 'description': "Краткое описание", 'content': "Содержание", 'posted': "Дата", 'author': "Автор", 'image': "Путь к изображению"} # метка к полю формы text
        labels = {'title': "Заголовок", 'description': "Краткое описание", 'content': "Содержание", 'posted': "Дата", 'author': "Автор", 'image': "Путь к изображению"} # метка к полю формы text
```

**newpost.html**:

```
{% extends "app/layout.html" %}
{% block content %}


    <h3>LДобавить статью</h3>
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        {{ blogform.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default" > Сохранить статьюЮ</button>
    </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Функция представления должна возвращать HttpResponse. У вас она его возвращает только если был POST-запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка типа ValueError возникает при несоответствии типов. В вашем случае функция newpost возвращает тип None вместо HttpResponse, если request.method не является 'POST'.

Функция newpost должна в любом случае возвращать HttpResponse, у вас она возвращает его только в случае, если запрос типа POST.

Есть вариант поставить в конец:

```py
return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: так?
        return render(request, 'app/newpost.html',
                {
                    'blogform: blogform,'

                    'year': datetime.now().year,
                }
            )
        return HttpResponse('Блог')

Comment: @Proka да, так, если не в одну строку поставишь